# Excluding one thread from executing boost::fibers

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-fiber

I'm creating a multi-threaded program which highly relays on `boost::fibers` when it comes to executing the actual execution heavy code.

**What I want to achieve:**

My main thread knows when to activate and run which fiber and when to collect the future provided after the execution of the fiber.
As my software is running in a highly parallel environment with over 100 cores, I start as many worker threads if possible. The worker threads should run a fiber scheduler like `boost::fibers::algo::work_stealing`. Therefore they should execute all the fibers my main thread produces.

**What's the issue:**

As my main thread is quite buisy with creating and timing all the fibers for the over 100 worker threads I want to avoid the main thread from joining the execution of any fibers.
This means, my main thread should solely care about starting fibers and gathering their futures after they completed executing.
*However, I do not know how to exclude my main fiber from executing fibers, too.*

**Possible, naive, solutions:**
Even though I don't know how to solve my problem properly, I thougt about a few possibilities.

1. Create my own fiber scheduler: The scheduler is a customization point of `boost::fibers`. Hence, there might be the possibility to wirte a custome scheduler which excludes the main tread from execution.
2. Use a `boost::fibers::buffered_channel` to transmit tasks between threads: However, I don't if this is a good solution as this removes the great possibilities from using a fiber scheduler.
3. Ohter great way I don't know yet: I gues there might be another, simple way from excluding the main thread, which creates the fibers, from participating in the execution scheduling of `boost::fibers`

As I'm quite new in the `boost::fibers` library, I wonder what is the best way to achieve my goal?

Regards and thank you for your help!